# How to permanently delete a commit from a removed branch?

Tags: git

How to permanently delete a commit from a removed branch so that it becomes unreachable?

```
* aa448ae (orphan) 
| * 1c0c419 (HEAD -> master) 
|/
* 0bfa9c3 

git branch -D orphan
git gc --prune=all
git filter-branch
```

And it's still available when I do:

```
git show aa44
```

or:

```
git branch test aa44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all dangling commits and those reachable from the reflogs:

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```